# How to calculate the probability of selecting a particular sequence of values if the selected values cannot be repeated?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

My friends and I are discussing the randomness of shuffling a playlist.

Lets say I have a playlist of $700$ songs, $30$ of which are by the same artist (its Pendulum, don't ask).

My understanding is that the number of possible shuffled playlists is equal to $700!$ (factorial, not enthusiasm). Assuming that the songs are not repeated after they are selected, that means that the probability of selecting any given sequence of songs is $\frac{1}{700!}$

How would I calculate the probability that all $30$ pendulum songs are played back to back? My gut says that this would be equal to $\frac{1}{700} \cdot \frac{1}{699}\cdot \frac{1}{698} \cdots \frac{1}{670}$. Is this instinct correct and if so, is there a more concise formula?

I used to know this stuff but haven't studies maths since I was $18$, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you care about the order in which the Pendulum songs are played back to back ?

Answer (score 0):

Without effort questions goes out of community standrad.
Still I am answering it.

Let, $30$ pendulum songs as $1$ unit song.

Now, $670+1=671$ songs can be arranged in $671!$ ways and $30$ songs can be arranged in $30!$ ways.

So, there is $671!\times 30!$ ways out of $700!$ possible ways to listen all pendulum songs in a row.

Threfore, Probability to listen all pendulum songs in a row$=\frac{671!\times30!}{700!}=(30!)\times\frac{1}{700} \cdot \frac{1}{699}\cdot \frac{1}{698} \cdots \frac{1}{670}$

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Sorry I'm new to the platform and wasn't sure what the standard format was/how to apply it. 

Out of interest, how would the formula change if the playlist is the same, but we are looking for the probability of playing just three pendulum songs in a row?

So $700$ songs in the playlist, $30$ of which are by pendulum, what is the probability of hearing any $3$ pendulum songs in a row without repeating songs?

Comment: And to add another layer, what is the probability of the *first* $3$ songs in the playlist being by pendulum?